# wordpress custom plugin translation file not working

Tags: wordpress, plugins, translation, poedit

I have a plugin with name "keydesign-addon" and I created file translation in my language and file loaded with below code:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'keydesign_addon_load_textdomain' );
function keydesign_addon_load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'keydesign', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
```

but plugin translation not working and it doesn't translate any words.
textdomain is "keydesign" and words are like this

```
esc_html__("App gallery", "keydesign")
```

I used "keydesign-addon-fa_IR.mo" and "fa_IR.mo" for file name but not working

also I installed "loco translate" to translate plugin but again not working

Comment: Have you set your plugin header like [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/#domain-path) ?

Comment: @awran5 unfortunately it didn't work!